# Ocaml pattern matching/ member of function

Tags: ocaml

The following function is trying to match a `(int * stmt list) list` (where `stmt` is just a type defined elsewhere) and return a `stmt list`.

```
 let rec findinlist (r: int) (l1: (int * stmt list) list ) (l2: stmt list) =   
      (match l1 with 
      | [] -> l2
      | h:: _ when h= (r,s) -> s
      | _ :: t -> findinlist r t l2
      )
```

First off this gives me an unbound value s error but how would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `when` it is not another pattern matching which would bind `s`. It is just a boolean test that expects a boolean (like an `if` statement).

Maybe you want something like:

```
let rec findinlist (r: int) (l1: (int * stmt list) list ) (l2: stmt list) =   
  (match l1 with 
  | [] -> l2
  | (r',s):: _ when r' = r -> s
  | _ :: t -> findinlist r t l2
  )
```

Comment: To elaborate a little, what @Sheeft is saying is that `when` takes a Boolean expression. It doesn't perform a pattern match, it's just a test (a predicate).

Comment: Yes, I was a bit too fast, maybe, I will add it to the answer (I hope you'll allow me).

Comment: I have no objection whatsoever. Happy to remove my comment after you make the change.